# AngularJS and PHP's json_encode

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a simple code here that uses json_encode and echo out the response in PHP. Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
$scope.login = function() {
        var data = {
            username: $scope.login.username,
            password: $scope.login.password
        };

        $http.post('endpoints/login.php', data)
        .success(function(response) {
            if(response.success == "true") {
                alert('nice');
            } else {
                alert('not nice');
            }
        })
        .error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

    };
```

**login.php**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=? AND password=?');
$stmt->execute(array($data->username, $data->password));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row > 0)
{
    $response = [
        "success" => true
    ];

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response = [
        "success" => false
    ];

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

It works perfectly but this part doesn't work:

```
if(response.success == "true") {
  alert('nice');
} else {
  alert('not nice');
}
```

When I add `console.log(response)` I get `Object {success: true} or Object {success: false}`.

Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Comment: `console.log(response)` and your answer might become clear.

Comment: @KevinB I get true or false, it works properly but I can't make the if statement work

Comment: I expected `response` to have a `data` property.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm sorry I don't understand but thanks

Comment: When you use `success()`, the data itself is passed in. FYI, `success()` is being deprecated, so you should use normal promise methods, such as `then()`

Comment: Ah, that's it. I never use .success, so didn't notice. :)

Comment: @AnidMonsur, I saw it in the documentation also. Will do! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a boolean in your if statement, not a string because `true != "true"`. Change your if statement to the following:

```
if(response.success === true) {
```

Comment: There you go. I did this but instead I used "true" which makes it not working also. Thank you.